# Standard Error of Mean Effect Size with User Supplied Weights (metafor)

Tags: meta-analysis, metafor

I am trying to estimate a fixed-effects model with user-specified weights and am a bit confused as to how metafor is calculating the standard error of the summary effect. The mean effect of the output is matching what I calculated manually but not the standard error. Below are the weights that I specified and my manual calculation of the standard error:

```
df$Weight
[1]  1.406896 17.919444 30.326004  9.735447  6.253869 13.385666 18.392949 24.906601
[9]  4.768206 10.736108 30.077368 18.370048 13.496598 38.654001 18.370048  6.509598
[17] 12.903948 78.165269  6.253869 12.903948  6.509598 68.438711  4.185651 13.496598
[25] 12.903948  6.509598 52.979206  9.735447  4.768206 37.613212  6.771612 86.282819
[33]  4.768206 48.193738 37.613212  4.768206 30.052294 80.361670 83.628525  6.509598
[41] 90.793506 12.380787 12.903948  4.768206 17.523037  4.768206  1.406896  4.185651
[49] 18.392949 17.523037 15.188166 12.380787 17.523037  6.253869  9.735447

sqrt(1/sum(df$Weight))
0.02856731
```

Fitting a fixed effect model in metafor with these weights produces the following, however:

```
Mod1 <- rma(yi = effect_size, vi = varOD2, weights = Weight, data = df, method = "FE"); summary(Mod1)

logLik   deviance        AIC        BIC       AICc 
-142.2222   415.2866   286.4444   288.4518   286.5199

I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   81.89%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  5.52

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 54) = 298.1999, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub 
 -0.1296  0.0152  -8.5445  <.0001  -0.1594  -0.0999  ***


---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Additionally, the weights that the model has read seem to be correct:

```
Mod1$weights
 [1]  1.406896 17.919444 30.326004  9.735447  6.253869 13.385666 18.392949 24.906601
 [9]  4.768206 10.736108 30.077368 18.370048 13.496598 38.654001 18.370048  6.509598
[17] 12.903948 78.165269  6.253869 12.903948  6.509598 68.438711  4.185651 13.496598
[25] 12.903948  6.509598 52.979206  9.735447  4.768206 37.613212  6.771612 86.282819
[33]  4.768206 48.193738 37.613212  4.768206 30.052294 80.361670 83.628525  6.509598
[41] 90.793506 12.380787 12.903948  4.768206 17.523037  4.768206  1.406896  4.185651
[49] 18.392949 17.523037 15.188166 12.380787 17.523037  6.253869  9.735447

> sqrt(1/sum(Mod1$weights))
[1] 0.02856731
```

What is also strange is that if I calculate a different weighting scheme then the produced standard error matches my manual calculation:

```
> df$Weight2 <- 1/df$varOD2

> Mod2 <- rma(yi = effect_size, vi = varOD2, weights = Weight2, 
+                   data = df, method = "FE"); summary(Mod2)

Fixed-Effects Model (k = 55)

  logLik  deviance       AIC       BIC      AICc 
-83.6788  298.1999  169.3577  171.3650  169.4332   

I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   81.89%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  5.52

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 54) = 298.1999, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub 
 -0.0398  0.0083  -4.7918  <.0001  -0.0561  -0.0235  *** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


> sqrt(1/(sum(df$Weight2)))
[1] 0.008303257
```

Does anyone know what might be happening here? I am trying to supply the weights calculated from a robust variance model so I can use the forest() function in metafor, but I need the confidence interval of the mean effect to match my RVE model (which matched the 0.029 calculation above).

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation you are using for computing the standard error is for the special case that the default weights are used. Consider this example:

```
dat <- dat.bcg
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat)
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat, method="FE")
res
```

You are using:

```
wi <- 1/dat$vi
sqrt(1/sum(wi))
```

which is appropriate for this case. However, the equation is a special case of the general equation:

```
sqrt(sum(wi^2*dat$vi)/sum(wi)^2)
```

which simplifies to the one you are using in this case.

This is no longer the case when using custom weights. A silly example:

```
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat, method="FE", weights=trial)
res
```

Then:

```
wi <- dat$trial
sqrt(sum(wi^2*dat$vi)/sum(wi)^2)
```

gives the correct SE, but not

```
sqrt(1/sum(wi))
```

In `Mod2`, you are using weights that are identical to the default weights, so this is why things work out as you expected for this model.